Tagging several consecutively aligned lines with one centered tag
I want to reference an equation that is too long to fit on one line, but I do not want the tag to be at the end of the second line. This is the current latex I have:
\begin{alignat}{3}\label{eq:polnomial_lagrange_form}
    p(x) &= -\frac{2}{6}x(x-1)(x-2) &&+ \frac{6}{2}(x+1)(x-1)(x-2)\notag\\
    &&&- \frac{21}{2}x(x+1)(x-2) + \frac{50}{6}x(x+1)(x-1)\notag\\
    &= -\frac{1}{3}x(x-1)(x-2) &&+ 3(x+1)(x-1)(x-2)\notag\\
    &&&- \frac{21}{2}x(x+1)(x-2) + \frac{25}{3}x(x+1)(x-1)
\end{alignat}


What I want is for the tag to be centred between the last two lines, somewhat similarly to the following example, which does so relative to all lines:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:q1_system}
    \begin{alignedat}{6}
        p(-1) &= 2  &&\implies& a_0 &+ a_1(-1) &&+ a_2(-1)^2 &&+ a_3(-1)^3 &&=  2\\
        p(0)  &= 6  &&\implies& a_0 &+ a_1(0)  &&+ a_2(0)^2  &&+ a_3(0)^3  &&=  6\\
        p(1)  &= 21 &&\implies& a_0 &+ a_1(1)  &&+ a_2(1)^2  &&+ a_3(1)^3  &&= 21\\
        p(2)  &= 50 &&\implies& a_0 &+ a_1(2)  &&+ a_2(2)^2  &&+ a_3(2)^3  &&= 50
    \end{alignedat}
\end{equation}


I have attempted using different variations of equation, split, and grouped align environments; however, each method either resulted in something invalid or as a result that is no longer aligned correctly.
Is this achievable?

So you want to center the tag with respect to the last two lines or the whole formula?

@Stephen With respect to the last two lines. I should have been a bit clearer. I will edit the question to further specify that.

Combine align and aligned to achieve this:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}\label{eq:polnomial_lagrange_form}
  p(x) & = -\frac{2}{6}x(x-1)(x-2)
    \begin{aligned}[t]
      & + \frac{6}{2}(x+1)(x-1)(x-2) \\
      & - \frac{21}{2}x(x+1)(x-2) + \frac{50}{6}x(x+1)(x-1) \\
    \end{aligned} \notag \\
  &
  \begin{aligned}
    = -\frac{1}{3}x(x-1)(x-2) & + 3(x+1)(x-1)(x-2) \\
    &- \frac{21}{2}x(x+1)(x-2) + \frac{25}{3}x(x+1)(x-1)
  \end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{document}



Ahhh, I did not think about using & before the environment itself! This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you :)
